# Symfony 3 | JMSi18nRoutingBundle exclude SonataMediaBundle routes

Tags: symfony-2.7, sonata-media-bundle

Guys I use **JMSi18nRoutingBundle** with some JMS bundles too, so I wanted to exclude **sonata media** routes, so i tried  : i18n = false

by this code

```
media:
    resource: '@SonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/media.xml'
    prefix: /media
    options: { i18n: false }
```

also i tried:

```
media:
    resource: '@SonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/media.xml'
    prefix: /media
    options:
      i18n: false
```

but i still got the links like this:
http://mysite.local/app_dev.php**/en**/uploads/media/Slider/0001/03/405f4n41adb162399344690cf85143c52a0ed147.jpeg